# Updated theme conflicts with updated php version

Tags: php, themes, updates

I have an old site that hasn't been touched in a while. If I update php version from the current one (5.something) to 8.something the site breaks because the theme version is too old; and I cannot update the theme because the latest version requires a more recent version of php.

Any suggestion on the strategy to fix this?

Comment: have you tried using a PHP version in the middle or updating both the theme and PHP at the same time? Updates don't have to be done via WP Admin they can be done via FTP/manually

Comment: Updating theme and PHP at the same time manually seems a viable option, thanks!